# How can I remove JQM styling on all children elements of div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

So I have a mobile app that uses JQM and twitter bootstrap, Basically I use JQM for navbars, navigation, etc but I don't want the content styled below a certain element called .content

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div class="content clearfix">

     //bunch of dom stuff here

    </div>
</div>
```

There are a few strategies I've tried that have failed

1. Wrapping the entire Jquery mobile css style sheet in with a :not(.content) selector somehow
2. Trying to select elements with any ui-* attribute and remove that class
3. Add a data-role="none" to all elemnets below .content

I feel like the first would be fastest but not quite sure how to do it heres what i have for method #3 On the event pagebeforecreate add data=role="none" to all elements

```
 $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', "[data-role=page]", function() {

   $('.content *',$(this)).each(function(index, value) {
         $(this).attr('data-role','none');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `data-enhance="false"` on your `container` element.
You will also need to enable to `Global Configuration` flag - `ignoreContentEnabled`

Be warned that setting `ignoreContentEnabled` causes performance degradation in page enhancement process.

Read the `Enhancement` Section of [Data Attributes Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/data-attributes.html)